# Create view (SQL) from a field with XML content

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle

I am working in Oracle DBMS and have a table where one of the fields has code in XML, and as such I wanted from this field to create a View. This same view should contain a set of attributes as those who own XML.
I already have a solution, however it is too cumbersome (there are about 50 fields) and wanted to expedite the process.

Piece of code that has the attribute
....

```
<AREAMEDIC200 titulo="campo1; " valor="False" />
<AREAMEDIC210 titulo="campo2; " valor="False" />
<AREAMEDIC220 titulo="campo3; " valor="True" />
```

....

Part of SQL

```
CREATE VIEW teste AS
Select NPROCESSO,
trim(extract(MENUXML, '//AREAMEDIC200/@valor')) AS c1,
trim(extract(MENUXML, '//AREAMEDIC210/@valor')) AS c2,
trim(extract(MENUXML, '//AREAMEDIC220/@valor')) AS c3,
.....
FROM TABELA1;
```

Anyone have any suggestions to make development faster?

regards

Comment: How are you going to use the view; do you really want to be able to find the true/false value for a given `nprocesso` and `titulo`? And what type is `MENUXML`, an XMLType? You haven't shown a root node - assuming there is one, are all the child nodes similar, just varying slightly in name but all with those two attributes?

Comment: The MENUXML is an attribute that contains this information. The ultimate goal is to get each field (CAMPO1 up CAMPO50) and create a column for each. This bit of code in XML must make a record.


id campo1  campo2    campo3
1 false   false     true

Comment: OK, but what data type is the column - if the data type is XMLType then there should be a top-level element in the XML; like `<TOPLEVEL><AREAMEDIC200 .../>< AREAMEDIC210 .../>...</TOPLEVEL>`?

Comment: Is not set, the XML code in this attribute MENUXML just have this aspect.

Comment: The XMLMENU is a varchar2.
Is useful but only tomorrow can I test at work.

Comment: [`extract()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions060.htm) takes an `XMLType` argument; how are you translating the `varchar2` in your table to an `XMLType`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `MENUXML` is of type XMLType, and has a root node, you can extract the values as rows with `xmltable`:

```
select t.nprocesso, x.titulo, x.valor
from tabela1 t,
xmltable('/TOPLEVEL/*' passing t.menuxml
  columns titulo varchar2(10) path '@titulo',
    valor varchar2(5) path '@valor') x

 NPROCESSO TITULO     VALOR
---------- ---------- -----
         1 campo1;    False 
         1 campo2;    False 
         1 campo3;    True
```

You can then pivot that into columns, but you'd still have to list the possible values somewhere - the number of values has to be known as parse time, so it can't be entirely flexible:

```
select *
from (
select t.nprocesso, rtrim(x.titulo, ';') as titulo, x.valor
from tabela1 t,
xmltable('/TOPLEVEL/*' passing t.menuxml
  columns titulo varchar2(10) path '@titulo',
    valor varchar2(5) path '@valor') x
)
pivot (min(valor) as v for (titulo) in ('campo1' as campo1, 'campo2' as campo2,
  'campo3' as campo3))
```

... **except** that causes a core dump in 11.2.0.3 (`ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [evaopn3()+125] [SIGSEGV]` if you're interested, which may be down to note 1580106.1 except the `NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE` hint doesn't help).

Since you haven't actually said you're on 11g, the old way of faking a pivot still works, but is slightly more work:

```
select nprocesso,
  max(case when titulo = 'campo1; ' then valor end) as campo1,
  max(case when titulo = 'campo2; ' then valor end) as campo2,
  max(case when titulo = 'campo3; ' then valor end) as campo3
from (
select t.nprocesso, x.titulo, x.valor
from tabela1 t,
xmltable('/TOPLEVEL/*' passing t.menuxml
  columns titulo varchar2(10) path '@titulo',
    valor varchar2(5) path '@valor') x
)
group by nprocesso
order by nprocesso;

 NPROCESSO CAMPO1 CAMPO2 CAMPO3
---------- ------ ------ ------
         1 False  False  True
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/900cd/1). The `pivot` version works there (11.2.0.2, I believe) as long as the hint is included.

You 'just' need to repeat the `max...` clause for each of the 50 possible values. Not sure if you'll consider that any easier than what you're doing now.

**Edit:** If `MENUXML` really is a `varchar2` you can convert it to an XMLType, and add a root node at the same time so it is allowed:

```
...
xmltable('/ROOT/*' passing xmltype('<ROOT>' || t.menuxml || '</ROOT>')
...
```